# Netty Server - Use with blocking Clients

Tags: java, android, netty, nio, blocking

I've set up a basic Netty 4 Server by the simple example Echo.
Now i'm sending some data to the Server on a blocking way:

```
socket.getOutputStream()
```

what works great but receiving data from the Server with:

```
socket.getInputStream()
```

wont show up any data receiving, just blocking. It's like the server isn't responding, but it does.

```
ctx.writeAndFlush()
```

For our suppose the clients should always work in blockingIO way.
It would be great if u could help me out with this.

**Got It**

After added `StringDecoder()` & `StringEncoder()` (using Json) to Pipeline - it works great.

```
.childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
            @Override
            public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {ObjectDecoder(ClassResolvers.cacheDisabled(null)),
                ch.pipeline().addLast("decoder", new StringDecoder());
                ch.pipeline().addLast("encoder", new StringEncoder());
                ch.pipeline().addLast("handler", new NettyServerHandler());
            }
```

Comment: Did you add any log to make sure the server receives the data sent by the client?

Comment: I did. It sysout the object before writeAndFlush() is called.